# Javascript fade in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, loops, web

In my custom Wordpress theme I am trying to animate all my table "nodes" in as the page loads simultaneously.

I can get this animation to work by applying the animation to each element individually but since trying to automate this process the animation fades all my nodes in at the same time and I do not understand why.

The below code generates my nodes...

```
    <div class="span12 news-tiles-container">
    <div class="row span12 news-tiles-inner">
        <?php 
            $node_id = 1;
            $node_size_id = 1;
         ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
            <?php 
                if($node_size_id > 3) {
                    $node_size_id = 1;
                }
            ?>

            <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
                <div class='node node<?php echo $node_id ?> size<?php echo $node_size_id ?>' 
                     style='background-image: url(<?php the_field( 'thumbnail' ); ?>);'>
                            <div id="news-caption" class="span12">
                                <p class="span9"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                <img class="more-arrow" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/more-arrow.png" alt="Enraged Entertainment logo"/>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </a>

            <?php
                $node_size_id++;
                $node_id++;
             ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am using the following code to control there animate in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Hide all of the nodes
$('.node').hide(0);

// Local Variables
var node_id = 1;
var nodes = 10;
var i = 0;


    while(i <= nodes)
    {
        $('.node'+node_id).hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

        node_id+=1;
        nodes--;

    } });
```

I assume it is something to do with my while loop, but the node counter increments successfully so it should be applying the animation to node1 then node2 then node3 and so on.

Thanks in advance
Alex.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve..? didn't get it. You want them to fade one by one?

Comment: yes thats correct, but currently they are all fading in together

Comment: NB: if there's only one node with each `.nodeNN` class you're doing it wrong - you should be using an `id` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your brandy dandy `.fadeQueue()`: [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rARAW/)

```
$.fn.fadeQueue = function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':last-child')) // making sure we are not done
            $(this).next().fadeQueue();
    });
}
```

This will wait for the callback of `.fadeIn()` for each div before moving to the next one..

Comment: Thanks for your response, I need to look more into what a fadeQueue does, I am relatively new to JS so a lot of these pre-built functions are new to me :)

Comment: This is not a prebuilt function. this just extends the jQuery library adding a new function to it :). this is a very good practice.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll definitely have to pick up some books on JS! I come from a .NET background so a lot of these problems I keep getting stump me

Thanks again :)

Comment: NB: this is a poorly behaving plugin. It doesn't allow "chaining", and if passed multiple elements it'll act strange too.

Comment: it's not really meant to be a fully extendible plugin. just to create the simple needed effect.

Comment: @YotamOmer A plugin that is not re-usable shouldn't be a plugin

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic plugin that will perform any animation you want, in sequence, on a jQuery collection of elements:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.queueEach = function (func) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1); // array of remaining args
        var els = this.get();                   // copy of elements
        (function loop() {
            var el = els.shift();
            if (el) {
                $.fn[func].apply($(el), args).promise().done(loop);
            }
        })();
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('.node').queueEach('fadeIn', 'slow');
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/D39Cw/

Comment: This answer should be marked as the real answer.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as elegant, but still works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.node').hide();
    $('.node').each(function(index,elem){
        setTimeout(function(){$(elem).fadeIn(1000);},1000*index);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nxjg2/)